# cascading dropdowns are not working in asp.net mvc4(razor)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have taken entity model.I need to bind second dropdown list based on first dropdownlist.I can able to pass first dropdown selected value to controller action,but i am not able to show values in second ropdownlist.Here is my view code,  COGPHome.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#productDetails').change(function () {
        //var productId = document.getElementById('ProductDetails');
        var productId = $(this).val();
        var prod = { ProductId: productId };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/COGP/GetProductFamily',
            type: 'POST',
            data: prod,
            success: function (data) {                   

            }
        });
    });
})
```

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div id="dvfilter">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Product:")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("productDetails", "---select---")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("ProductFamily:")
        </td>
        <td>               
            @Html.DropDownList("productFamily", "---select---")                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is controller code

```
public class COGPController : Controller
{
    COGPEntities objEnt = new COGPEntities();
    public ActionResult COGPHome()
    {
        List<refProduct> objListproducts = new List<refProduct>();
        objListproducts = (from c in objEnt.refProducts select c).ToList();

        ViewData["productDetails"] = new SelectList(objListproducts, "ProductId", "Product");
        ViewData["productFamily"] = new SelectList(string.Empty);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetProductFamily(int productId)
    {   
        List<refProductFamily> objListfamily = new List<refProductFamily>();
        objListfamily = (from f in objEnt.refProductFamilies select f).ToList();            
        ViewData["productFamily"] = new SelectList(objListfamily, "ProductFamilyId", "ProductFamily");            
        return View();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting ajax called? if yes then what is in success? have you checked using `console.log(data)`?

Comment: We tried to keep the alert in the success but it is not firing (i mean it is not going to success method). In the browser console i'm getting this error "POST http://localhost:15229/COGP/GetProductFamily 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
`Script`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ProductName").change(function () {
     firstDDLValue = $("#ProductName").val();
      $.post("@Url.Action("ItemList", "Admin")", {fstValue: firstDDLValue }, function (result) {
       var select = $("#ItemId");
        select.empty();
        select.append($('<option/>', {value: '0', text: '--Select--' }));
        $.each(result, function (index, Data) {
       select.append($('<option/>', {
       value: Data.Value,
        text: Data.Text
          }));
         });
        });
       });
     });
     </script>
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult ItemList(string fstValue)
{
 PurchaseStock PS = new PurchaseStock();
  int ProductId = 0;
  if (fstValue != "")
  ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(fstValue);
  var result = PS.GetItemForDrop(Convert.ToInt32(ProductId));
  IList<SelectListItem> Data = new List<SelectListItem>();
  for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
   {
    Data.Add(new SelectListItem()
    {
      Text = result[i].Text,
      Value = result[i].Value,
    });
  }
 return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In View:

```
<select id="ProductName" name="ProductName" class="dropdownlist"> </select>//First Dropdown list
<select id="ItemId" name="ItemId" class="dropdownlist">//SecondDropdown
```